# How to execute intragroup statistics on other fields after grouping by the same continuous data?

Tags: dolphindb

The below picture displays the table schema:

[image]

I group the table by symbol field first. Now I want to count the counts that how many diff_price are greater than 0 and how many diff_price are less than 0 in a group. Take an example: in the following flag series, 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1......, the same continuous digits 0 generate the first group, the continuous digits 1 generate the second group, etc. The expected result is as below:

symbol          date           >0        <0

sh600000   2020.09.24    2     12

sh600000  2020.09.28     0    2

Answer (score 0):

DolphinDB has a segment function for segmented statistics. Try the following code:

```py
select last(date) ,sum(diff_price>0),sum(diff_price<0) from t context by symbol,segment(flag)
```